# How to avoid Chrome trace events from overlapping

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, trace

We generate logging events in the trace ui format and there are few cases where [complete events](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CvAClvFfyA5R-PhYUmn5OOQtYMH4h6I0nSsKchNAySU/preview#heading=h.lpfof2aylapb) overlap with each other. They dont appear in different rows. 
How can I avoid such overlap? Example trace is

```
{
"traceEvents": [
{ "pid":1, "tid":1, "ts":87705, "dur":956189, "ph":"X", "name":"Jambase", "args":{ "ms":956.2 } },
{ "pid":1, "tid":1, "ts":87755, "dur":956189, "ph":"X", "name":"Jambase2", "args":{ "ms":956.2 } },
{ "pid":1, "tid":1, "ts":128154, "dur":75867, "ph":"X", "name":"SyncTargets", "args":{ "ms":75.9 } },
{ "pid":1, "tid":1, "ts":546867, "dur":121564, "ph":"X", "name":"DoThings", "args":{ "ms":121.6 } }
],
"meta_user": "aras",
"meta_cpu_count": "8"
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the above trace where 2 complete events overlapped with each other.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the `chrome://tracing` can't avoid this kind of overlap. In your example, all of the data belongs to the same thread. One thread can't process multiple tasks simultaneously. You can change the `tid`s of the overlaped elements when generating the json to make them displayed in different lines.

I once wrote a script to meet this need. Supposing that `ts`s are in increasing order, `N` is the maxium overlap level. The following pseudocode shows how to change the `tid`s of overlaped elements.

```
n_start = [0] * N
for element in traceEvents:
    for i in range(N):
        if n_start[i] < element['ts']:
            n_start[i] += element['ts'] + element['dur']
            element['tid'] += i
            break
```